# How do I get my application to show up in the add people on ios notes menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10, uti

Sharing feature of iOS Notes. 
[Link.](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT206987)

I see one feature of iOS notes collaborate. 
wants to open my application contacts in sharing and allow access to contacts of my application.

Which [UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) useful here ? I read full list of it but not sure, Is it link, data or else ?

Now, How do i get my application to show up when any user Click on add people ?

[image]
how to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure, Check out `share extension` it may help.

Comment: @Gokul Now it showing in menu, But i could not share with my app's contact like whats app !!

Comment: **Now it shows with share extension, but not able to share text like WhatsApp !!** Click on App icon from share menu, not redirect to open my app, It just open one post dialog and nothing later..

Answer (score 0):

glad to hear that `Share extrension` works,

- The share dialogue opens is a default one from `SLComposeServiceViewController`,Documented as

  > The SLComposeServiceViewController class provides a `standard compose view` you can present for social sharing extensions on both platforms.
- To `UIViewController` is direct parent of `SLComposeServiceViewController` so you can customise your share dialogue as your wish.
- So simply change the class’s inheritance to that of `UIViewController` and delete all of the SLComposeServiceViewController-specific methods.Use `UITableView` to list out all your contact list in `ShareViewController.swift`
- View [this](http://catthoughts.ghost.io/extensions-in-ios8-custom-views/) for reference. And bellow image is my demo share dialogue.

  [image]

**EDIT:** For your reference added my `ShareViewController.swift` code

```
    import UIKit
    import Social

    class ShareViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {

      @IBOutlet var languageTable: UITableView!

      var languageList = ["Swift","Python","Java","ObjC",".Net","php"]


      override func viewDidLoad() {
        languageTable.dataSource = self
        languageTable.reloadData()
      }

      func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
      }

      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return languageList.count
      }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text = languageList[indexPath.row]
       return cell
     }

    }
```

Comment: I have did with Action Extension.

Comment: Sounds good, if you got time check this solution.It helps others